# As a variable approaches $\infty$, can a function approach another function of the same variable?

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, infinity, boundary-value-problem

The question I'm working on is about the Laplace equation in polar coordinates, regarding the velocity field of a perfect incompressible fluid in the plane.

The problem is to solve the Laplace equation $$\frac{1}{r}\partial_r(r\partial_r\phi)+\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_{\theta \theta}\phi=0,$$

with boundary conditions
$$\partial_r\phi=0 \text{ for } r=R \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \phi \rightarrow Ur\cos\theta \text{ as } r \rightarrow \infty,$$
where $U$ is the velocity far away from the disc ($\phi$ is the flow outside of a disc of radius $R$).

What I am unclear  about is the boundary condition $\phi \rightarrow Ur\cos\theta \text{ as } r \rightarrow \infty.$

This seems completely unintuitive. My interpretation reading this is that as $r$ approaching infinity, we have that a function $\phi(r,\theta)$ approaches $Ur\cos(\theta)$, and since $-1\le \cos(\theta) \le 1$ we will have that $Ur\cos(\theta)$ just oscillates between negative and positive infinity. How does this boundary condition make sense?

Comment: In asymptotic analysis we find approximations to functions as the value of a parameter approaches infinity. We could write $f(x;\lambda) \sim g(x;\lambda)$ as $\lambda \longrightarrow \infty,$ where $f$ and $g$ are _both_ dependent on $\lambda.$ This is understood to mean that, as $\lambda$ becomes very large, the error between $f(x;\lambda)$ and $g(x;\lambda)$ becomes very small, without necessarily carrying out the limit $\lambda \longrightarrow \infty,$ so that we still see each as a function of $\lambda.$ However, I've never seen that sort of thing in a boundary condition before.